# Use Kotlin android extensions in Custom class

Tags: android, kotlin

*edited*

I'm using kotlin for my project.

Especially, Kotlin android extensions.

When activity or fragment there's no problem.

I want to use this feature in my custom class. (without experitemtal layoutContainer)https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#layoutcontainer-support

Now I use extension by this way.

```
// some class 
// pass rootView 
val nameTextView1 by lazy {rootView.tv_name1}
val nameTextView2 by lazy {rootView.tv_name2}
val nameTextView3 by lazy {rootView.tv_name3}
val nameTextView4 by lazy {rootView.tv_name4}
val nameTextView5 by lazy {rootView.tv_name5}
```

<s>do anyone know some fancy way?</s>
I want to remove duplication of "rootView". any idea?

Comment: What do u mean by fancy? This is just one line of code with less than 50 chars, what else do you expect?

Comment: I literally couldn't understand your question.

Comment: same here. I don't understand.